# How to group FCM notifications when app is killed by Android

Tags: android, notifications

I want to group FCM notifications when application is killed,

I know the OS is using setGroup for grouping when app is in foreground.

```
    Notification summaryNotificationWithBackground =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
    .setContentTitle("2 new messages")
    ...
    .extend(wearableExtender)
    .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
    .setGroupSummary(true)
    .build();
```

But when App is in the background ***MyFirebaseMessagingService*** is not called.

So how to group messages when app in background or application is kill.

Comment: Did you get the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle notifications when the app is killed, you can have a look at Firebase Data Messages. You can handle data messages even if the app is in background. You can have a look on this [FCM Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: Yes, we can send using "data" in JSON payload but how to group them when the app is killed?

Comment: If you are sending a data message (and not a display message) the onMessageReceived is called even if app is killed so you can group the notification even when the app is killed in the same way you group it when the app is in foreground.